# auto increment or update age column every year mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask about updating the age column in my table. Is it possible to update the age automatically every year based on date of birth column in my table. the age column and the date of birth column are in the same table. But if it isn't possible, maybe I just update the age table every time I select the age column with calculating the age from the date of birth column. I just kinda curious if there's an instant way to do it.

Comment: Don't use an Age column; record Date Of Birth, and calculate age based on that.

Comment: You could use the event scheduler to update the age columns periodically.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah I thought about it that way too. But I'm kinda curious is there any way to do it. if it isn't possible, maybe i just drop the age column

Comment: If you use a (possibly custom) function, you can determine the age on demand.  Unless you're age criterion is something like 'Age on 31st August', the ages continually change, so you'd have to adjust some ages every day (if you want the ages in whole years).  You're usually better off using a function.

Comment: thank you all. After read spencer explanation, I will using the select method based on the DOB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store "age".  If you have a DOB column, then "age" is simply the difference between the current date and time, and the DOB.  If you want "age" calculated as of a particular date, then it's still the difference between that date and the DOB.

You can use the MySQL builtin `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function to calculate "age" in years, for example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '1993-10-01' ,NOW()) AS age_in_whole_years
```

Subsitute in your DOB column for the literal in that expression. That will be calculated automatically whenever you run a statement that includes this expression. You can't get more "automatic" than that.

If you need to "search" based on age, use a predicate on the DOB column instead.  To find rows with "age" less than 21, then DOB is less than 21 years ago, that is to say, the DOB is greater than today's date minus 21 years. e.g.

```
 WHERE t.dob  > NOW() - INTERVAL 21 YEARS
```

---

**To answer the question you asked:**

No, there's nothing in MySQL that will "auto increment or update" a value stored in an "age" column. (To change the value stored in a column, you need to run an UPDATE statement.)  You can setup a scheduled task to run periodically, but that task is going to need to issue an UPDATE statement. You could call that "automatic" if you wanted to.

(The people smart enough to design database software think about stuff like this; they already know that "auto increment" of a stored "age" column is a bad idea, all around. There's already a better solution.)

I'm pretty sure that StackOverflow doesn't store the "age" of questions and answers, "asked 1 hour ago", or posted "4 months" ago. For them to rip through the tables, to update a row for every question, every comment, every answer... that would be insane. All they really need is store the date and time something was posted, they set it and forget it... no churning of update statements, obtaining exclusive locks, generating undo/rollback, writing to the redo logs, that would just be hammering the database.  For retrieval, they are already doing all the work of running SQL to retrieve the row, the posted date time is there, they just retrieve that, and its a negligible amount of processing to the "age" calculation.